# Wiring Motor to DPDT Polarity Switch

Tags: motor, switches, wiring, reverse-polarity

I am trying to wire my motor (US Motors, Model: C55JXKNL-5041) to a polarity reverse switch. The diagram printed on the motor is as follows:
BLU ____L1
BRN ____INS
BLK ____INS
ORG _^
WHT _^
YEL ____L2
RED _^

There is also a note printed on the motor saying "To reverse rotation interchange RED & BLK Leads."
I am able to wire up the motor and it works properly but only in one direction. I can't figure out how to wire it so that my 6-pin polarity switch will flip the red and black leads as indicated while still properly tying together the other leads.

Here are images of the [Motor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/US-MOTORS-1-4HP-Motor-Frame-56-1725-RPM-115-208-230V-1-Phase-Cradle-Mount-/291843623223?_trksid=p2047675.l2557&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&nma=true&si=8JwPtBqTeTqCb0kgLA4UxT8s%252Fh4%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc) and [Switch](http://www.ebay.com/itm/162003381648?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) that I'm using. Hopefully this will be helpful.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the motor is designed to be reversed without first shutting it off and waiting for it to coast to a stop. You need two switches. You need a simple on/off switch to connect and disconnect the power. The second switch is used to reverse the motor by interchanging the red and black lead connections to the "INS" and "L2" groups of wires. That requires a switch similar to the one that you have except that is does not need a center "off" position.

You should probably download the instructions for this motor if you don't have them.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm not sure why I couldn't figure this out before. I guess I had a mental block. :P